# MinGW "undefined reference to IMG_Load/IMG_Init/IMG_Quit" LazyFoo

Tags: c++, reference, g++, mingw, sdl

I am going off of LazyFoo's SDL2 tutorials for C++ using the MinGW g++ compiler (using console).  I have followed his page [here](http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson03/windows/mingw/), step-for-step. I have finally come across this error after having downloaded his example.

[image]

I have seen plenty of people online struggle with SDL_Image, but I've not yet seen this and I haven't found any solution to it yet.

- I've loaded the include and lib folders with the proper assets
- I've copied all necessary .dll's to my compile destination
- The example LazyFoo provides includes for SDL_Image and SDL itself

*(this question my sound redundant, but I've yet to come across a solution that applies to console-compilation)*

Comment: Have you actually installed the SDL_image library? Where is the library file (libSDL_image.a) located?

Comment: I just did a search and I do not even 'have' libSDL_image.a, so it's apparent that I've not properly (or at all) installed it. (I got everything I have currently from https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: I solved this because it tunerd out you also need to add -lSDL2_image when compiling.. just like it was suggested in the picture. thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the comments above, the answer seems to be:

You need to install the development libraries for SDL_image.

You can download them here: https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/
(look under the heading "Development libraries").

You need to ensure the path where the `libSDL2_image.a` file resides is in the linker search path. One way of doing this is to add an appropriate `-L` parameter to the link command. You could also drop the file in the default library search path.

Answer (score 2):

I've had this problem in linux. the solution is simple.
add to linker:

```
-lSDL2_image -g `sdl2-config --cflags --libs`
```

[image: project build otpions, switches added to Other linker options]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, and the solution was to include the SDL2main library in linker parameters.

For Dev-C++ IDE you can follow the instructions below:

[Get SDL or SDL2 working correctly with Dev-C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39311982/get-sdl-or-sdl2-working-correctly-with-dev-c/48922659#48922659)